# spring boot serving html files nested in templates folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I am currently trying to place a html file inside a folder, but I am getting the following error
Error resolving template "secondTest", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

[Image of controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBDMa.png)
[Image of html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqPYY.png)

My understanding is that as long as a folder or html file is placed in the templates folder, spring boot should find it.

Solution: ModelAndView mw = new ModelAndView("testfolder/secondTest");
I was not pointing my in the right directory.

Comment: can you give a try changing to `tesfolder/secondTest` in ModelAndView

Comment: value = "testfolder/secondTest" thorws me 404 error

Comment: ModelAndView mw = new ModelAndView("testfolder/secondTest"); Omg this resolved my problem, thank you very much!